# Sun 'goes down' or 'comes down'?

Tags: meaning, differences

A couple months ago I read a book with the statement **When the sun goes down** and today in a movie I saw the man said **Let's wait for the sun to come down**. I believe both are refering to the sunset.

But which of them is better to be used or are there any formal differences between the two sentences?

Comment: When the sun goes down, it disappears under the horizon. Could it be that this man was waiting for the sun to get nearer the horizon but not disappear? Like in some vampire movies the friendly vampire can handle dusk but not full sunlight? I would not personally use "come down". The movie "Rio" has a song called "when the sun comes down". And it is idiomatically correct to say "when the sun comes up"

Comment: Do you remember the beautiful song: Don't Let the Sun Go Down on Me?

Comment: I would say "go down" has a *slight* negative connotation (as in, do not want) versus "come down", but not sure.

Comment: The sun comes up. The sun goes down. First-person point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When the sun goes down** is the common use and form for a setting sun (as oppose to the *sun comes up* for a rising one).

The image in my head is a person standing on the beach in the evening waiting to take a photograph of the setting sun.

**Let's wait for the sun to come down** seems to imply that you're waiting for the sun to catch up to you for some reason (as if you're ahead of the sun).

The image in my head is a person standing on the beach in the late afternoon and telling his/her friend(s) that they should stay until the sun reaches them and sets in the distance.

There seems to be no *formal* difference, just a directional thing. I guess if your back is to the horizon and you're not watching the sun there, it's *coming* to you. And if you're facing the horizon and the sun is there, then the sun is *going* from you.

On a side note, there are lyrics of songs with both versions.

Answer (score 2):

The sun comes up and goes down.  It is the language of appearance - when it comes up, it is appearing from below the horizon and when it goes down, it is disappearing below the horizon.  I've never heard anyone use the expression "wait for the sun to come down" - to me it sounds like they expect it to land on their head.